# Is there a Django setting, that can prevent javascript from calling external API

Tags: django

I manage a Django project collaborating with different front end programmers. Sometimes in my html template I have

```
<script src="https://example.com/script.js"></script>
```

Is there a way that I in my settings.py define whitelisting external domains that can be called. In this example, if `example.com` is not whitelisted, calling to that domain should be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

### settings.py

```
ALLOWED_JS = ['example.com', 'example2.com']
```

### template

```
{% for domain in ALLOWED_JS %}
<script src="https://{{domain}}/script.js"></script>
{% endfor %}
```